Sheaves of modules over a topologically ringed space
Topologically ringed spaces turn up a few places in the literature (most notably in EGA 1's construction of formal schemes), but I can't find much general information about them (e.g. the nLab page is three sentences long).

General question.
Let $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ be a topologically ringed space: a ringed space where $\mathcal{O}_X$ is further a sheaf of topological rings (as in MO:403007).
Has it been investigated as to what structure this extra topological information endows on the category of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules (if we require the $\mathcal{O}_X$ action to be continuous)? e.g. does this become a topologically enriched category? or something else?

Maybe this general question is somewhat meaningless without a bunch of extra conditions, so let me give a specific example.

Specific question.
Let $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ be a complex space. Then $\mathcal{O}_X$ can be endowed with the compact convergence topology, and Grauert and Remmert (1979) showed that the category of coherent sheaves inherits a lot of nice properties: for every coherent sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ and open $U$, we get a Fréchet topology on $\mathscr{F}(U)$, and the restriction maps are continuous; on $\mathcal{O}_X$ this is exactly the compact convergence topology; every morphism of coherent sheaves is continuous; ... .
What extra structure does $\mathsf{Coh}(X)$ gain? Is this explored somewhere in the literature?

I understand that the modern response to wanting "to do algebra and analysis at the same time" is to look at the theory of condensed mathematics, so maybe an answer lies there, but I'm not familiar enough with the field to be able to find it if so.

I think it's important to distinguish between linear topology on a ring (with base of 0 formed by ideals) and "Euclidean-like topology" on Frechet sheaves and similar. First one gives a torsion pair on the abelian category of O_X-Mod, which (in case when topology satisfies some "finiteness" conditions) induces an exact localisation functor to the subcategory of "smooth" (as they are called in infinite Galois theory) modules. ...To be fair, in this case we're interested not in topology, but in a filter of subfunctors of Id on O_X-Mod.
